Were there ways to hide some files in old Unix?
According to Rob Pike, hiding files with a preceding dot was a mistake. So before this modification in ls behaviour (hiding files starting with a '.' by default) was made, could people hide files from a directory listing with ls or other tools? Or did they see all files all the time?
Were there filesystems with hidden attribute like FAT?

One person's opinion that it was a mistake on a random Google Plus thread doesn't exactly strike me as a sound source for an authoritative declaration.  That notwithstanding, the idea of a file being hidden (as opposed to "not displayed by ls by default") seems antithetical to the concept of file or directory ownership.  If I own a directory, it should not be possible to hide its contents from me, in my opinion.

That ls bug was already in v1 in 1971, used by a handful of person. What was before that was more proof of concept material and with a design likely in a flux. Even if there was a ls command then, how you could hide a file to it was likely not in anyone's mind. In any case, that would have been long before FAT or Microsoft.

@DopeGhoti: (1) Rob Pike is not a ‘‘random’’ person.  He was part of the team that developed Unix (presumably he was actually on a first-name basis with Ken Thompson & Dennis Ritchie).  He (with Brian Kernighan) co-wrote The Unix Programming Environment and other important works.  ... (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) … (2) The question mentions FAT’s “hidden” file attribute — do you also consider that to be “antithetical to the concept of file or directory ownership”?

phuclv: I doubt that “commit was merged” is appropriate here.  While I don’t see any dates in Rob’s post, we can assume that the events happened in 1971 (see this ancient ls man page) — long before SCCS was created.

The idea may have come from Rob Pike - 12 years ago - but the idea that files filtered out of listings by default is a bug...is a flawed idea.  Many users of Unix-style systems do not need to see the names of every file on disk.  As someone who, in 1983-4 had to re-build MS-DOS boot floppy disks for executive assistants and clerks because they saw the COMMAND.COM file and, out of curiosity, ruined the file by opening it in the Wordstar word processor...I state emphatically that so-called "hidden" files is not a bug.  Especially when a simple -a option will show them.

@SottoVoce, see the last paragraph in Rob Pike's rant.

@SottoVoce and Stéphane and that last paragraph is what we increasingly get with $XDG_CONFIG_HOME; most programs that a office worker would need keep ~ clean and drop their configs under $XDG_CONFIG_HOME (which translates to a single .config directory in $home)

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica': right: SCCS, RCS, cvs didn't exist at this time. We were using diff -e :).

@SottoVoce, even if a feature is later consider to have merit doesn't mean it can't originally have been unintended and undesired, i.e. a bug.

A key point worth considering: the . starting file names exception was not inside the Unix file system. This was a default behaviour integrated at the command level, and only inside ls & sh ( the original Bourne one, * evaluation ). There was not the slightest modification at the file system or the kernel level.[↵][Source: IRTS!]

In regards to the question posed to me (and I will not comment further as this is not the venue), the concept of file or directory ownership is entirely foreign to FAT, so it's irrelevant to discussion of a UNIX/POSIX filesystem.

The author goes on to say, literally,

I'm pretty sure the concept of a hidden file was an unintended consequence.

So, the concept did not exist before within their operating system.

The concept of hidden files existed (see the reference to TOPS-20 by Stéphane Tsacas in the comments from Aug 3, 2012) but not as an implementation that hid files starting with a dot

@ChrisDavies yep, but I wouldn't call TOPS-20 an "old UNIX" as per the question's title – hence my "within their operating system"

From a prehistoric witness: there was no such concept of hidden files in the old versions of Unixes ( BSD & System V ). [↵]
Apple is trying to implement such a function at the Finder level, but it's rather an ill conceived make up. Moreover it creates new generation of incompetent users, which is not the best idea.

In short: there was no concept, just a bad programming side effect :).

@dan not really necessary to incorporate Rob's authority here. This is pure text work, not even incorporating the technological relevance of the author.

Right! ⇒ removed my suggestion..
